# Try on catch block and continue execution if succeeded

Tags: c#, exception, sqlexception

Hi have the following method on a static class that I would like to retry 'x' number of times in case there is an specific exception type.

Right now, this is how it looks like.

```
public static void myMethod(DbContext context, ISettings settings)
{
    try
    {
        RefreshDb(context, settings);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error on method RefreshDb", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Do something here 
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to capture one specific exception type (in this case SqlException) and retry the call to RefreshDb few times over a timespan of 60 seconds. Once I capture the exception, how can I retry several times and also...

- If it success then leave the catch block without throwing and continue the execution of my code (finally part in this case)
- If it fails, throw a real exception.

.

```
public static void myMethod(DbContext context, ISettings settings)
{
    try
    {
        RefreshDb(context, settings);
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        // Call RefreshDb here again.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error on method RefreshDb", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Do something here 
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer your question, the initialization of a new context object does the trick here. That's why I want to try to reinstansiate the context again before calling the RefreshDb. Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry if my example was misleading but no, it is in the catch block where I will instansiate the context again and then call the RefreshDb method again (if that makes sense). (re added for readability :))

Comment: IMHO dont do this, have the caller handle it, but you would need to make it a return, not the static method... Of course there are many ways to do it, for example a scoped int to keep how many tries it did...

Comment: What if you do your exception handling things in `RefreshDb`. If you get your desired exception, here, `SqlException`, then change the database context and call `RefreshDb` recursively.

Comment: Stop reusing your contexts (which 99 times out of 100 you shouldnt be anyway), and your problem is solved

Comment: I've not used it myself but I've heard lots of good things about [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly): "Polly is a .NET resilience and transient-fault-handling library that allows developers to express policies such as Retry, Circuit Breaker, Timeout, Bulkhead Isolation, and Fallback in a fluent and thread-safe manner."